# Could 佛州 mean Vermont, or does it always mean Florida?

Tags: transliteration, place-names, abbreviations

The Chinese translation of Vermont (佛蒙特) and Florida (佛羅里達) both start with "佛". When people say "佛州", do they exclusively mean Florida? Or could Vermont also be called "佛州"?

Comment: This reminds me of how, at Nankai University, 南大 refers to Nankai, but elsewhere 南大 refers to Nanjing University.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be used to refer to either state, however, it is more often referred to as Florida rather than Vermont, because most of the Chinese are more familiar with the former, for it's a popular destination for the tourists, and having more Chinese reside there.

I won't be surprised to hear the reply "噢,佛蒙特州.沒聽過,在那兒?" :)